# Delete old Backup Files in SharePoint

Tags: powershell

I want to use PowerShell script which delete old Backup Files in SharePoint2010 Backup Folder. I've found this script:

```
# Location of spbrtoc.xml
$spbrtoc = "\\XXX\spbrtoc.xml" 

# Days of backup that will be remaining after backup cleanup.
$days = 7 

# Import the Sharepoint backup report xml file
[xml]$sp = gc $spbrtoc 

# Find the old backups in spbrtoc.xml
$old = $sp.SPBackupRestoreHistory.SPHistoryObject |
? { $_.SPStartTime -lt ((get-date).adddays(-$days)) }
if ($old -eq $Null) { write-host "No reports of backups older than $days days found in spbrtoc.xml.`nspbrtoc.xml isn't changed and no files are removed.`n" ; break} 

# Delete the old backups from the Sharepoint backup report xml file
$old | % { $sp.SPBackupRestoreHistory.RemoveChild($_) } 

# Delete the physical folders in which the old backups were located
$old | % { Remove-Item $_.SPBackupDirectory -Recurse } 

# Save the new Sharepoint backup report xml file
$sp.Save($spbrtoc)
Write-host "Backup(s) entries older than $days days are removed from spbrtoc.xml and harddisc."
```

but I get 2 errors back:

> Exception calling "RemoveChild" with "1" argument(s): "Object
>   reference not set  to an instance of an object." At line:1 char:50
>   + $old | % { $sp.SPBackupRestoreHistory.RemoveChild <<<< ($_) }
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
>
> Remove-Item : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is
>   null. At line:1 char:23
>   + $old | % { Remove-Item <<<<  $_.SPBackupDirectory -Recurse }
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Remove-Item], ParameterBinding    ValidationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,M
>   icrosoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand

Comment: Looks like script did not find the spbrtoc.xml file....are you sure you give the correct path of the file and correct filename?

Comment: remember to use sp mgmnt shell as a admin too

Comment: It could save the new spbrtoc.xml file but it couldn't delete the old folders